# Can a thrown exception be accessed in a C++ catch(...) block

Tags: c++, gcc, exception, gdb

I have GDB attached to a process that is currently inside a `catch(...)` block.

**Is there a known technique to access that thrown exception?**

The program in question is a gcc/x86-64 binary, but I'm also curious about other builds.

Comment: Yes, of course it still exists, but since you don't know its type, what are you going to do with it?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can do some RTTI on the active exception object. Check your ABI documentation; it might just describe something like that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, you can re-throw it, so you can re-throw it inside another `try/catch` block with more specific clauses to extract the exception (and another `...` if you want as well).  You can even do this inside another function so you can centralize your exception handling.

Edit:  I misunderstood the importance of `gdb` in your question, but you can apply the idea I described.  Make a function that re-throws the exception you can set a breakpoint in:

```
void
helper()
{
    try {
        throw;
    } catch (int i) {
        // anything that won't get optimized away
        volatile int j = i;  // breakpoint here
    }
}
```

Then in `gdb` just do `call helper()`.  I just tested this to be sure it worked.

Further edit:  If you literally mean *I'm running a program under gdb* **right now** and you are not exiting `gdb` until you are sure you can't get the exception, then it's time to look at `eh_throw.cc` and friends in the `gcc` source.  `__cxa_rethrow` starts with:

```
  __cxa_eh_globals *globals = __cxa_get_globals ();
  __cxa_exception *header = globals->caughtExceptions;
```

You will have to examine all of those structures to figure out what's buried inside.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this - but the exception (or at least a pointer to it) should probably be on the stack somewhere close to the head. I guess the exact position and format is implementation dependent, but you should be able casting different addresses in this area of the stack to your exception type (or at least to std::exception) and see if you get meaningful results.

Comment: The exception can't be on the stack, since it has to persist during stack walkback.  Most implementations have some special, separate area where they allocate them, but this area isn't accessible from C++.

Comment: @James - But a pointer to it is probably be on the stack. And a copy of the exception can be on the stack - you can have this code: 'catch (std::exception ex)', which copies the exception. It is unlikely that the '...' is implemented that way, but it's possible

Comment: I've never seen an implementation where a pointer to it was on the stack.  The semantics of a `catch` are more or less those of a function: if you catch by value, you get a local copy; if you catch by reference, a reference to the exception, and if you `catch(...)`, the runtime doesn't put any more on the stack than when it calls a function without args.

Comment: Well, as the OP said, it is reasonable to assume there's something on the stack since it can be rethrown. But you're right. It's not mandatory. It can be implemented another way.

Comment: @Asaf: It's rethrown from the "special area" that James Kanze mentioned. Note that you rethrow with `throw;` - it doesn't need a copy of the exception.